# How to extract elements in an array that have multiple entries?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a large vector that contains monotonically increasing data or a duplicate, looking something like this:

```
data = [0 1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4 4.4 4.4 4.4 5.5 6.6 6.6 6.6 7.7];
```

In this data set, I'm interested in the *duplicate* entries (in this case, `4.4` and `6.6`). I have a sorta clunky solution to extract these values, but I feel like MATLAB should have a one-liner solution to extract a result like

```
result = [4.4 6.6];
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The combination of [**`unique`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and [**`diff`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) is enough, `find` is actually not necessary.

```
out = unique(data(~diff(data)))
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's another option using just [`hist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html) and indexing:

```
result = data(hist(data, data) > 1);
```

Answer (score 4):

My one liner:

```
unique(data(find(diff(data)==0)))
```

Test it [here](http://goo.gl/H0PJdA)!

---

**Explanation:**

1. with `diff` you get the differences from one element to the next.
2. **As the array is previously ordered**, the result of the above line will **output zero on the repeated ones**.
3. With `find(result_from_above == 0)` I get where they live (indexes
   for zeroes)
4. With `data(result_from_above)` I get the repeated elements, and then
   apply unique to get them.

**Update:**

You can use logical indexing, as @rayryeng said, you dont need the `find`, then it becomes:

```
unique(data(diff(data)==0));
```

Then test it [here](http://goo.gl/XBKhcC)

Comment: Using `find` is unnecessary.  Logical indexing is good enough: `unique(data(diff(data)==0))`

Comment: Nice.  Now if you remove the `==0` and replaced it with `~diff(data)`, you would have what thewaywewalk has in his answer.

Comment: @rayryeng. In this case I prefer the ==0, for its clearer for the reader. I'd also suggest not putting it all in one line like I did on the answer, because it makes it less readable.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following.

```
[~,index]=unique(data);
unique(data(setdiff(1:length(data),index)))
```

the `index` will have the indexes for the unique values, the `setdiff` will remove those index from the `1:length(data)` vector which are the non-unique index values. Then these are indexed with the `data` vector and again unique is applied to get as you require.